# Pass required argument to optional

Tags: python, function, syntax, arguments

Trying to make a board, which must be a square if there as only one argument (and a rectangle if there are two of them).

Code sample:

```
class Game:
    def __init__(self,h,w=h): # lookie-lookie 
       self.board = [[0 for i in range(w)] for j in range(h)]
```

What I expect:

```
b = Game(2)
b.board
#should return [[0,0],[0,0]]
b = Game(2,1)
b.board
#should return [[0],[0]]
```

What i got:

```
NameError: name 'h' is not defined
```

How should I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At function definition, the value passed to optional arguments is evaluated, however, in that instant, `h` is not defined. You can instead use a sentinel value as a placeholder for the optional argument:

```
class Game(object):
    def __init__(self,h,w=None):
        if w is None:
           w = h
```

If you're on Python 2, remember to subclass `object`.

Comment: Already did it.
Just looking for some features of Python that i didn't know.
Thank you anyway.